# how to add animation on anchor tag using CSS

Tags: html, css, angular-material

```
<div class="btnContainer">
  <a class="homeBtn">
    Go Home
  </a>
  <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" class="rightArrow">arrow_right_alt</mat-icon>
</div>
```

I have this button code. Basically on hovering the **btnContainer**, I want the icon to be displayed with a little animation of the arrow going to right side.

this is my style sheet:

```
.btnContainer{
    background: #fb8ab0;
    border: none;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1rem;
    transition: ease-out .5s;
    justify-content: center;
}

.homeBtn{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.rightArrow{
    display: none;
    margin-left: -1rem;
    transition: ease-out .5s;
}

.btnContainer:hover .rightArrow{
    display: block;
    transition: ease-out .5s;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: What animation? Do you mean the transition?

Comment: yes that's what I want. Can you help me with it. the icon displays but there is no animation like a little moving forward transition effect

Comment: To have a transition the system needs to know both what you are transitioning from and what you are transitioning to. - for example a left: position change.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `display` from css. Use opacity instead. And add `transition: all ease-out 0.5s;`

```css
.btnContainer {
  background: #fb8ab0;
  border: none;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  transition: ease-out .5s;
  justify-content: center;
}

.homeBtn {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.rightArrow {
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: -1rem;
  transition: all ease-out .5s;
}

.btnContainer:hover .rightArrow {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all ease-out .5s;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="btnContainer">
  <a class="homeBtn">
    Go Home
  </a>
  <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" class="rightArrow">arrow_right_alt</mat-icon>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks alot ..it works fine for me